# Html.ActionLink not filling up the href attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Route definition:

```
context.MapRoute(
            name: "VeranderingsTraject",
            url: "Detail/{action}/{id}/{viewDate}/{toekomstBeeldId}",
            defaults: new { controller = MVC.Detail.Name, action = MVC.Detail.ActionNames.VeranderingsTraject, viewDate = UrlParameter.Optional, toekomstBeeldId = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { typeof(DetailController).Namespace }
        );
```

DetailController:

```
public virtual ActionResult VeranderingsTraject(int id, DateTime? viewDate = null, int? toekomstBeeldId = null)
    { ... }
```

ActionLink in view:

The current view is actually also from the DetailController so I thought that I didn't need the controller name. Since it wasn't working, I added it, but to no avail.

```
@Html.ActionLink(linkText:"TEST LINK", actionName: "VeranderingsTraject", controllerName: "Detail", routeValues: new {id= 1, viewDate = Model.VersieDatum}, htmlAttributes: null)
```

Result in browser:

```
<a href="">
    TEST LINK
</a>
```

Expected result:

```
<a href="/Detail/VeranderingsTraject/1/{date, i need to encode the url i know)/">
    TEST LINK
</a>
```

Comment: you're using Razor syntax, is that also what you selected as view engine for your view?

Comment: Yes, I selected the razor engine and for the most part it is working. It's just this snippet that doesn't want to work (the actionlink)

Answer (score 1):

So after some reading left and right (thank you google)

Seems that my routing was done completely wrong. So I cleaned up my whole routing table and now I'm getting a lot better results, it's still not perfect, but it can be fixed thanks to the answers given on other ActionLink related questions here on stackoverflow

I have about 10 actions on the detail controller giving the same view (shared info amongst different objects) I used to have a route for each of these so the correct route could not be determined.

Now all 10 routes are brougth to this one:

```
context.MapRoute(
            name: "Detail",
            url: "Detail/{action}/{id}/{viewDate}/{toekomstBeeldId}",
            defaults: new { controller = MVC.Detail.Name, action = MVC.Detail.ActionNames.Persoon, viewDate = UrlParameter.Optional, toekomstBeeldId = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new[] { typeof(DetailController).Namespace }
        )
```

The generated link is now the following:

```
<a href="/Atlas/Detail/persoon?id=14&requestDate=01%2F22%2F2014%2000%3A00%3A00"></a>
```

So I just need to format that date a bit better and then read up to change the /persoon?id=... to /persoon/14/01-22-2014/ but I've seen some questions and answers on stackoverflow to remedy that problem.

Thanks for reading and thinking, hope this helps somebody